# what parameters does the function texture() takes?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

```
float texture(gsampler2DArrayShadow sampler, vec4 P, [float bias]);
```

Look at this function in OpenGL ES (shader lang). I do not understand the difference between `gsampler2DArrayShadow` and `sampler2DArrayShadow`. Can you explain this? I read that 'g' can mean nothing or i or u. But what then is this type?

Also, Does '[float bias]' mean that we have 2 functions: with this parameter and without?

Comment: What version of GLSL ES are you talking about here, by the way? I re-re-tagged this OpenGL because assuming GLSL ES 2.0 (which is what compilers/good developers are supposed to do if no GLSL ES version number is given), the function prototype you listed is from OpenGL and not ES. ES 2.0 does not have `texture (...)`, it still uses `texture2D (...)`, etc.

Comment: OpenGL ES 3.0. There is this function in: http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/texture.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you see a variable type in GLSL prefixed with `g` in a function prototype, that is a shorthand convention that means there is an overload for every type of data. A function that accepts `gvec`, for instance, means it has an overload for `ivec`, `uvec`, `vec`, `dvec`, `bvec` and so on.

Desktop GLSL has support for integer samplers in addition to fixed-/floating-point so you will see a lot of functions defined using `gsampler...` instead of `sampler...`, that means the function has `isampler...` and `usampler...` overloads in addition to the more traditional variety.

---

As for `[float bias]`, that is used to control mipmap LOD bias. When you do not supply a value to that parameter, GL computes the bias itself.

Interestingly because of the way mipmap LODs are computed, only the fragment shader variety of the texture lookups support automatic mipmap selection (it has to do with the per-fragment derivative calculation). To use mipmapping in the vertex shader, you have to explicitly select the LOD with `textureLod (...)` or supply your own partial derivative using `textureGrad (...)`.